# Property with one of (setter or getter) with body

Tags: c#

This question is just out of curiosity. I have a property as below

```
public static int MyProperty {get;set;}
```

which compiles successfully, but when I do

```
public static int MyProperty {
    get
    {
        return 5;
    }
    set;
}
```

OR

```
public static int MyProperty {
    get;
    set
    {
        value = 10;
    }
}
```

Then I get errors

> 'ClassName.MyProperty.set' must declare a body because it is not
>   marked abstract, extern, or partial

And

> 'ClassName.MyProperty.get' must declare a body because it is not
>   marked abstract, extern, or partial

respectively.

My question is why it is fine not to provide body to both getter and setter but body for either with give an error?

Comment: @Hogan at what place?

Comment: You have to do both if you override one.  cf https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/get

Comment: When asking "why feature X is implemented that way" it is always good idea to pause for a moment and try to implement feature the way you want and come up with explanation why this is good behavior aligned with the rest of the framework/language/platform. In this case explanation would be something like "this is great idea because now you have more convenient syntax for property where `set` has no way to impact `get` which is very useful for ..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because when you use this: `{ get; set; }` is called an auto-property and it just a shortcut for having a backing field. Is the same as this:

```
{ 
  get { return _field; }
  set { _field = value; }
}
```

But this can't work with only one of both parts.

Answer (score 2):

Any property should define logic for its getters and setters, if there are.
Empty getter or empty setter doesn't make any sense.

However, when you define a property like this:

```
public static int MyProperty { get; set; }
```

you tell C# to automatically generate backing field and use for simple equivalent implementation:

```
// This is actually what it means:
private static int _myProperty; // name for simplicity

public static int MyProperty
{
    get { return _myProperty; }
    set { _myProperty = value; }
}
```

or if expand it further:

```
// This is actually what it means:
private static int _myProperty; // name for simplicity

public static int get_MyProperty()
{
    return _myProperty; 
}

public static void set_MyProperty(int value)
{
    _myProperty = value; 
}
```

When you define a property with one auto-getter and coded setter, it doesn't really make much sense. What do you expect the property's `get` to do in this code?

```
public static int MyProperty {
    get;
    set
    {
        value = 10;
    }
}
```